# Not able to register the services as eureka client

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-3, java-21

we are using the spring boot 3.2.1 and spring cloud 2023.0.0 versions.

when we are running the services, the services are running but they are not getting connected to the eureka server.

```
2024-01-03 07:52:39,081 ERROR com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_ACCOUNT-SERVICE/dev-2.internal.cloudapp.net:account-service:8092 - was unable to send heartbeat!
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:837)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1401)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

We tried using @ImportAutoConfiguration({FeignAutoConfiguration.class, EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.class})

sometimes all the services are getting connected and sometimes none of the them gets connected (mostly after doing git pull).

```
build-file
------------
nohup mvn -f discovery-service spring-boot:run > /dev/null 2>&1&
mvn -f ncaish-core/account-service/account-service-core spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 &
nohup mvn -f ncaish-core/account-agg-service/account-agg-core spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
nohup mvn -f ncaish-core/detax-service/detax-service-core spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
#nohup mvn -f ncaish-core/kyc-service/kyc-service-core spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
nohup mvn -f ncaish-core/notification-service spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
nohup mvn -f ncaish-core/fx-service/fx-service-core spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
nohup mvn -f ncaish-core/retirement-service/nps-service-core spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
nohup mvn -f ncaish-core/ffs-service/ffs-service-core spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
nohup mvn -f ncaish-core/wealth-service/wealth-service-core spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
nohup mvn -f ncaish-gateway spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
nohup mvn -f ncaish-auth-server spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
nohup mvn -f ncaish-core/report-service/report-service-core spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev-2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
```

Comment: I would follow code changes on the commit(s), when you 'git pull' and loose server connection. Try git diff, or even better some visual git tool.
It will be probably somewhere in network/connectivity configurations (your services vs eureka).

Comment: and there was no configuration changes made that impacts the network between the eureka and services